# Install4J- error during installation of an application in Windows

Tags: install4j

A user get an error when trying to install on his devices:

**trying to install keep getting error 34
here is the log file
Please let me know what i need to do.  i tried it on my laptop and got the same error*

```
Started executable C:\Users\damon\Downloads\windows-x32_1_2(2).exe at Fri Oct 08 16:06:43 2021

[0:0] restrict DLL directories
[0:0] init file name C:\Users\damon\Downloads\windows-x32_1_2(2).exe C:\Users\damon\Downloads\windows-x32_1_2(2).exe 53 0
[0:0] number of sections: 5
[0:0] size of optional headers: 224
[0:0] resSectionTableStart: 672
[0:0] rawDataSize: 16384, rawDataOffset: 381440
[0:0] sun.locale.formatasdefault is false
[0:0] language/country is en_US
[0:0] ignoring java options environment variables
[0:0] change working directory to C:\Users\damon\Downloads
[0:0] single instance mode
[0:0] semaphore name Local\c:_users_damon_downloads_windows-x32_1_2(2).exe, code 0, value 00000178
[0:0] Init done
[0:65] Starting work
[0:72] number of sections: 5
[0:72] size of optional headers: 224
[0:72] resSectionTableStart: 672
[0:72] rawDataSize: 16384, rawDataOffset: 381440
[0:73] starting at 397824
[0:73] verifying integrity length 52948869
[0:169] ERROR: check ReadFile failed 0 0 47984108*
```

any idea what's happening? I tried on multiple machines and works all the time

Together with installation package i distribute the FTDI drivers for the hardware. Could this be the issue (picking the "resctrict DLL directories" hint from the log)?

Answer (score 0):

This error would happen if the file is truncated.

Comment: Hi Ingo, thanks for reply. Yes, i figured it out it was not an issue with installation builder but just a trivial truncated file not related to Install4j